# Font Awesome HTML

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста.
Есть `input[type='submit']`

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск мероприятия">
    <input type="submit" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

Сейчас он пустой `value='q'`. Как сделать чтобы на его месте была либо png картинка (лупа) либо символ из Font-Awesome (тоже лупа)
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задаем класс необходимой fontawesome иконки, в качестве `value` задаете [юникод символа](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/) :

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 40px;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск мероприятия">
    <input type="submit" value="&#xf002;" class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Это то что мне нужно было

Answer (score 2):

> Как сделать чтобы на его месте была либо png картинка (лупа) либо символ из Font-Awesome (тоже лупа)

Вот так на пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск мероприятия">
    <!-------- Тот же эффект, что у input[type="submit"] -------->
    <button type="submit">
       <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое